# COVID-19 in US healthcare: who pays for testing?

Tags: united-states, healthcare

If, as a US citizen or resident, I had flu-like symptoms and if I was not covered by Medicaid/Medicare and didn't have health insurance, who would be liable for paying for COVID-19 test diagnostics in a US hospital?

I saw an offhand remark about "the cost and people not getting tested as a result", in an online forum.  It wasn't even a claim that it was happening, more like a quip that it might happen.

The US healthcare vs Euro/Canadian-style coverage debate has been done to death, but it usually revolves around the problems lack of coverage brings **to the people who are ill**.  This is not what I am asking about.

An epidemic situation however brings a different dynamic:  there's a vested interested **for everyone** else that sick people are identified as such and isolated, it's not **just** about the being well-being of the patients.  To assist in containment, you want to remove as many barriers to early diagnosis as possible.

Is there/could there be some form of emergency funding for at least the tests themselves, at the federal level?  One model is for example, the financial arrangements around vaccination programs.

#### Edit:

the question concerns the procedure for the entire test, i.e. lab services as well as clinic time:  seeing a doctor/nurse, taking the tests and getting the results.  Nothing more, but also all of what's necessary for a YES/NO answer wrt having COVID-19 or not.

Bryan's answer is great wrt to the kit and lab services themselves, but someone still needs to interview you and take whatever samples are necessary to send off for testing,

Do these arrangements vary by state?  Or does the Federal govt, through the CDC, have jurisdiction?

State vs Federal:  it seems to me that a Federal-level guidance ought to be faster than waiting for all 50 states to come up with their own programs individually.

Comment: anything done by a hospital that's "not covered by Medicaid/Medicare and (for someone who) didn't have health insurance" is paid for by the patient. In certain situations, various public health organizations (think county clinics, planned parenthood, health districts, free clinics, etc) use funding or donations to offer low/no-cost testing to such citizens, but afaik, there's none of those available for covid-19 yet.

Comment: Re: your edits...the rest of my answer includes those other costs (which in this case would be included in the hospital bill if hospital staff were doing the testing): as of now, the patient has to pay unless someone simply decides not to bill them. There is no other funding source. I added a bolded statement in case this wasn't clear from the longer text.

Comment: @BryanKrause yes, I had already understood that.  thing is, I'd like to really differentiate someone who has an ambulance + a quarantine stay from someone who just walks into a clinic/hospital, doesn't need anything else and just gets tested.  the minimal case possible, but still needs the interview.  are they potentially on the hook for say $500+?  that would not be good.  not for them, but also certainly not on the larger population who relies on appropriate quarantines.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**The [CDC covers the cost of testing itself](https://www.ahip.org/keeping-americans-safe-from-coronavirus-covid-19/)**, however, this may not be the only type of cost incurred.

---

[A recent New York Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/02/29/upshot/coronavirus-surprise-medical-bills.html) presents a case study of exactly the sort of scenario described in the question.

Americans who were living in China and evacuated from Wuhan did not have health insurance in the US and were given a $3,918 bill for care during quarantine, including $2,598 for ambulance transportation. Neither ultimately tested positive.

> He did receive a document upon leaving quarantine directing him to contact a government email address with any medical bills. He sent an email on Feb. 24 detailing the charges and asking what would be done.
>
> “My question is why are we being charged for these stays, if they were mandatory and we had no choice in the matter?” Mr. Wucinski wrote in his message.
>
> He has not received a response, he said.

Since then, after being contacted by the Times, the hospital stated the bill was in error:

> When contacted by The New York Times, a Rady Children’s Hospital spokesman said the physicians’ bill had been sent in error and that the family would not be held responsible for the charges.

..but it is not clear whether this is a matter of policy or a public relations move by the hospital, nor is it clear how these matters will be handled going forward. It also does not yet resolve the $2600 ambulance bill (of course this is all still pending).

The government can order mandatory quarantines, but as far as who pays:

> “There is no uniform practice,” said Lawrence Gostin, a professor of global health law at Georgetown University. “They do have the powers, but they’ve almost never used them in modern times.”

**Without some new government intervention, it seems that for now costs will either be charged to patients or simply absorbed by the treating facilities (by not billing).**

---

The [American Hospital Association and American Nurses Association](https://www.aha.org/press-releases/2020-02-27-aha-ana-urge-congress-quickly-fund-health-care-readiness-coronavirus) on Feb 27, 2020 have asked for the government to fund care related to the epidemic. It seems likely that there will be further political fights over what exactly is done next.

---

*update: As of March 4th, 2020, an agreement was reached in the House on a bill for COVID-2019 funding, which is expected to pass there and later in the Senate. This bill does not address how to deal with care and testing for the uninsured, though it includes state and local funding. It's unclear at this time how those funds could/will be used:*

> Congress didn't explicitly address how to handle funding for mandatory quarantines or the uninsured. The package would send $950 million in state and local grants, with half of the money due within 30 days. States will receive a minimum of $4 million.

https://www.politico.com/news/2020/03/04/coronavirus-funding-package-121209

Comment: Americans can be made to pay for their prison-related expenses, especially huge fees for home detention supervision. I can't see why the capitalistic principles would not be applied here, i.e. pay for their own quarantine.

Comment: @Fizz because if someone is sued in court they can argue there was never any agreement to pay.  A person involuntarily detained has not signed any contract or otherwise consented to their treatment.

Comment: @Viktor: I'm sure agreement can be obtained along the lines of "sign here and we quarantine you in a nice hospital or don't and we take you to Gitmo (or some other remote US military base)"

Comment: @Fizz sounds like one can plausibly argue duress in that circumstance.

Comment: @Viktor: isn't the same choice with home detention (fees)?

Comment: There's already [outrage](https://www.cnbc.com/2020/03/02/cdc-released-a-woman-in-texas-who-tested-positive-for-the-coronavirus-totally-unacceptable.html) that the CDC released someone who then tested positive. So I wound't put it beyond the plausible that the "default quarantine" is going to be in a place farther away from now on.

Comment: could you add the date when the AHAANA... first made that request?  it is not dated on their site, but if you Google for the quoted full title, it looks as if it first shows up Feb 27th.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Yes the date is clear in their individual letters, I've added it here. This sort of thing is probably not best for the SE format - I've answered as well as I can for this moment in time but of course everything is dynamic in a situation like this. It's hard to balance information with definitive answers.

Comment: *"the bill was sent in error"* - this usually means "we hope that some people will not contest it and so we'll get easy money from them."

Comment: Stories like these that will make people hesitant to get tested.

Comment: It is well known that US hospitals have an "invoice first, ask questions later" kind of attitude to their patients...

Comment: @Viktor: This is not uncommon. Do you pay tax? I'm willing to bet you didn't agree to do that. It's a principle in many states that if you have property (or assets) you are out of luck. Only if you have debt, you're pretty safe. For example, when your mayor (whose brother owns a construction company) decides that the pavement in the street you live in is going to be renewed, you will be paying around 50-60k, whether you agree with that pavement being renewed or not. You may have to sell your house, and guess what, nobody cares. It's 100% legal, and being done.

Comment: @Viktor I very much doubt that everyone in prison "agreed" to be there either (especially, but not limited to, those who will later be shown innocent or wrongly convicted)

Comment: @Damon by the US Constitution the federal government is generally prohibited from imposing a direct tax other than income tax. Since this quarantine in the scope this question seems to stem from federal action to defend this money being taken from you under the federal government’s power would generally at the minimum require passage of a taxing statute by congress and also apportionment of this tax duty among the states. Also the act (Public Health Service Act) allowing quarantines seems to have several amendments that violate the origination clause under this interpretation...

Comment: @Chronocidal they were convicted of a crime. The judicial system cares little about actual innocence unless you can prove it by preponderance of the evidence or better. Once convicted of a crime the ideas of due process no longer apply. A person in quarantine has committed no crime.

Comment: Your answer seems to pretty much cover the current state of affairs.  I'll accept it, but do you mind either modifying it, or letting me accept another, if and when more definitive arrangements are made at the federal level?  or in most states?   I hope that the govt realizes they really need to take $ worries out of the testing mechanism and fix it too, ASAP.  Living in Vancouver, we're 2 hours drive away from what seems like a new hotspot in Seattle, hardly reassuring.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica You don't need my permission to accept another answer if a better one comes along. Unfortunately, the SE model isn't great for dynamic situations - I'll surely edit if I can but also don't want to change an answer too much that has already been voted on. I agree with you that this is an important thing; for many, their insurance should cover their care, but others will have co-pays, have to pay out of a health savings acct, or are simply not insured. US healthcare is a bit of a mess - be glad you're north of the border.

Comment: I know what you mean about ongoing events.  recently a question became active about what Bernie Sanders's path to nomination after Super Tuesday's defeat(?).  I was puzzled about the wording and context until I realized it was the 2016 campaign.  if things change sufficiently i could also edit the title to say As of "March 2, 2020"...

Comment: and the reason I was asking about acceptance is that SE puts a number of "freezes" on things, unless the answer or question changes.  say you vote to close, then realize you didn't like the reason given.  you try to change it, can't.  so you withdraw vote, then vote to close again with the new reason.  can't => question hasn't changed.  not sure this is the case or not with an acceptance.